# I want to declare a pointer array to character without using string

Tags: c++

Here is the code::

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 4;

int main ()
{
  char key[20];
  char *names[MAX];

  for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
  {
    cout << " entr keys\n";
    cin >> key;
    names[i]=key;
    cout<< names[i];
  }
  for(int i=0; i<MAX;i++)
  {  
    cout << names[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I enter the keys and print them in the 1st `for` loop they show the right value, but when I print `names[i]` in the 2nd `for` loop it keeps showing the last key entered again and again.

Please tell me: where am I going wrong?

Comment: `without using string` Your code shows exactly why you should be using string, you seem to have no idea how raw arrays work and how to copy data around. Hint: this `names[i]=key;` does not copy what `key` points to, it merely copies the `key` pointer itself.

Comment: You need enough space for 4 strings like `key`, and you need to make sure the `names` elements point to those, rather than always pointing to `key`.  And you need to use `strcpy()` or `memmove()` to copy the key into the other strings.  Or, better, use `<string>` and `string` so you don't have to worry about it in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `names[i]=key;` you don't really copy `key`'s string value to `names[i]`.
It just makes `name[i]` point to where key is (since both `name[i]` & `key` are pointers).

so all in all you're overwriting `key` several times, and making all of `names` pointers point to key.

You need to copy those strings either by working with `std::string` instead of `char*` or by using `strcpy`. I'd recommend on working with `std::string`.

Using `std::string` your code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 4;

int main ()
{
  string names[4];

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    cout << "entr keys" << endl;
    cin >> names[i];
    cout << names[i];
  }
  for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
  {
    cout << names[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time you execute the lines

```
cout << " entr keys\n";
cin >> key;
```

you're inserting a null-terminated string into `key`, e.g. `"hello\0"`.

Afterwards you copy `key`'s address and store it into a cell of the names pointers array:

```
names[i]=key; // Now I point to 'key'
cout<< names[i];
```

then the cycle starts again. Anyway from the second time on you're **inserting null-terminated strings into key** and thus overwriting the previous contents. The second time if you had entered `"hi\0"` the contents of the `key` array would become

```
['h', 'i', '\0', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0']
```

anyway you're going to only print the first string since the null terminator will prevent the other content from being displayed.

When the program ends you're going to have four pointers to the same key array and that array will only contain the last element inserted which overwrote the previous ones.

In order to solve you can make your array a bidimensional one (or use a [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) array):

```
const int MAX = 4;

int main ()
{
  char key[4][20]; // <- Now this has two indices
  char *names[4];

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    cout << " entr keys\n";
    cin >> key[i];
    names[i]=key[i];
    cout<< names[i];
  }
  for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
  {  
    cout << names[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/7IlYES)

Answer (score 1):

Corrected program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>

const int MAX = 4;

int main ()
{
  char key[20];
  char *names[MAX];

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    cout << " entr keys\n";
    cin >> key;
    names[i] = new char[strlen(key) + 1];//names[i]=key;
    strcpy(names[i], key);
    cout<< names[i];
  }
  for(int i=0; i<MAX;i++)
  {  
    cout << names[i];
  }
    for(int i=0; i<MAX;i++)
  {  
    delete [] names[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You need to allocate space for each names[i] and when done, deallocate
also, changed the hardcoded 4 to MAX